# Setting up Gender in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

What's the best way to set up a gender field in Rails 3? I'm using PostgreSQL.

I currently have it as a string but am wondering if it would be easier (better?) to set it up as an integer. If so, how would this be done? I want to produce a drop down for it including three values: "Male", "Female", "None of your business".

Sorry for the basic question but I'm curious as to simple, best practices.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what domains are for:

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE DOMAIN gender CHAR(1)
    CHECK (value IN ( 'F' , 'M' ) )
    ;

CREATE TABLE persons
    ( pname VARCHAR
    , gend tmp.gender
    );
INSERT INTO persons( pname, gend) VALUES ('Alice', 'F') ,('Bob', 'M') ;
INSERT INTO persons( pname) VALUES ('HAL') ;
INSERT INTO persons( pname, gend) VALUES ('Maurice', 'Z') ;

SELECT * FROM persons;
```

The output:

```
DROP SCHEMA
CREATE SCHEMA
SET
CREATE DOMAIN
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 2
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  value for domain gender violates check constraint "gender_check"
 pname | gend 
-------+------
 Alice | F
 Bob   | M
 HAL   | 
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 6):

An enum seems best:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-enum.html

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Mike Jones.  ENUM's are perfect for this.  ENUM's are awesome for smallish sets of values that rarely change.  Gender is a perfect example of this.  Usually you only need 5: Male,Female,Intersex,Transgender,Unknown. Tho many go with 3: Male,Female,Other.  2 however (Male,Female) is mean to those that are not male or female.

Answer (score 1):

How about using a simple `is_male:boolean` field?

Or `is_female`, if you prefer.

Either way, nil (null) should not evaluate to true or false by default.

Comment: This is a very restrictive solution. The native enum type provides a lot more specificity.  Also "Either way, nil (null) should not evaluate to true or false by default." is not true.  null values are evaluated to falsey values in ruby.

Answer (score 0):

## Very easy:

Just use enum:

```
CREATE TYPE gen AS ENUM ('f', 'm');

CREATE TABLE lawyers_tb (
  ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR,
  gender gen
);

INSERT INTO lawyers_tb (name, gender)
  VALUES ('Jose Luis Gonzales', 'm');
```